# Error on EditForm.aspx and DispForm.aspx, blank page?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, sharepoint-addin, list-form, edit-form

Suddenly I get this error when trying to edit an item from a list, also when I try to view it.

It happens on these files:

- EditForm.aspx
- DispForm.aspx

It happens when there is an ID parameter:

```
DispForm.aspx?ID=7
```

If I load EditForm.aspx or DispForm.aspx without ID they work, but this is useless, just telling you for debugging purposes.

I have no idea what to do. I have tried to replace the code from a working EditForm.aspx, this did not help. I have tried to delete recent columns I made,to see if they created a conflict, did not work

Can you help?

**Error code:**

```
     <html>
       <head>
          <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=utf-8">
          <meta name="Robots" content="NOINDEX " />
       </head>
       <body></body>
       <script type="text/javascript">
          var gearPage = document.getElementById('GearPage');
          if(null != gearPage)
          {
              gearPage.parentNode.removeChild(gearPage);
              document.title = "Error";
          }
       </script>
    </html>
```